# Delete based on index, without knowing where it is

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex` and I know it has two levels and  `year` is in the first one, and I want to keep particular years, I can do

```
df = df.loc[yearStart:, :]
```

If I know the index has only two levels, but not in which `year` is, I can hack some dirty

```
if df.index.names[0] == 'year':
    df = df.loc[yearStart:, :]
else
    df = df.loc[:, yearStart:]
```

What if I know it is in the index, but not which level, nor how many levels the index has? If `year` is not in the index, but a regular column, I can do

```
df = df.loc[df.year >= yearStart]
```

Is there something similar generic for the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_level_values` to get a column-like view of an index level.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(100)}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(10), range(2010,2020)], names=['idx1', 'year']))

df.head()
Out[41]: 
           a
idx1 year   
0    2010  0
     2011  1
     2012  2
     2013  3
     2014  4

df[df.index.get_level_values('year') >= 2015].head()
Out[42]: 
           a
idx1 year   
0    2015  5
     2016  6
     2017  7
     2018  8
     2019  9
```